# Stack trace dumps entire class object in custom resource

Tags: chef-infra

Did an upgrade from Chef 12 to Chef 17.10.3. I was using `chef-solo` and have now changed this to `chef-client -z`. When there's an error in a custom resource I get the whole class dump instead of the class name previously.

Any ideas? I still want the more helpful stack trace info, just not this full dump. It makes the file huge and is not particularly helpful as one huge line of text. **Seems to be isolated only to custom resources (so far).**

Here's my command: `sudo chef-client -z -c /opt/chefsolo/solo.rb --environment ENV -N HOSTNAME -j /opt/chefsolo/node.json -l warn`.

And here's the contents of solo.rb:

```
repo_dir =        "/opt/chefsolo"
chef_repo_path    repo_dir.to_s
file_cache_path   repo_dir.to_s
cookbook_path     "#{repo_dir}/cookbooks"
role_path         "#{repo_dir}/roles"
data_bag_path     "#{repo_dir}/data_bags"
environment_path  "#{repo_dir}/environments"
```

My `/opt/chefsolo/node.json` file only has a run_list defined.

**Updated**

Here's the recipe:

```
ruby_block "get user list" do
  block do
    node.default["authorization"]["add"]["users"] = %w[user1 user2]
  end
end

brazen_users_users "Create and config users" do
  user_list(lazy { node["authorization"]["add"]["users"] })
end
```

And here's the resource:

```
property :user_list, Array, required: true

action :run do
  user_list.each do |user|
    puts user
  end
end
```

To be clear, I know that `user_list` in the resource needs to be `new_resource.user_list` (https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/#example-resource).
My question is not "why is this resource not working?" My question is "why when this fails does it print the whole class information ?"

Comment: I guess there's an error i your question, chef-client -v doesn't match chef-solo nor zero. BTW chef-solo use chef-zero under the hood since somewhere in chef 12, so I don't get your question at all. If you get an entire node dump with attributes, that's something in your recipes, not in chef code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as needing details, as without your recipe code and/or a log that's impossible to guess what could cause your observations.

Comment: Edited `chef-client -v` to `chef-client -z`. I understand that chef-solo use chef-zero under the hood since somewhere in chef 12, but I'm upgrading from Chef 12. The version I was using hadn't yet combined the two. The error I'm having is with a custom resource that doesn't display the same huge dump of ohai. The difference? Chef 12 vs. Chef 17 as explained in the question.

Comment: There's been some changes to custom resources in 15, namely using unified mode by default, without the custom resource code (or a link to the cookbook repo) or a log of the error, this question can't be answered.

Comment: I added the recipe and resource. I know why the resource is failing. I am trying to understand why the error message is so unreadable and if there is a way to fix that.

Comment: Ok, I get it, the NameError exception returns the whole class dump instead of just the class name, unsure if it's a ruby 3.0 thing of Chef related. (CV retracted)

Comment: Yeah, it could be Ruby 3. With the upgrade I'm clearly also upgrading from Ruby 2.3.6 to 3.0.3. Here's why I think it's Chef though: (1) I can't reproduce the same problem in irb. (2) If you look at the dump it seems to be more than just the class object. I'm seeing hostname information, attributes set on the node, etc. (unless custom resources inherit all node attributes).

Comment: The node object is one of the property passed to the class defined by the custom resource (so you can access node attributes in the resource), so it's expected to be seen in the full class inspection, previsouly only the class name was shown in the error, so for now I guess it's a change in ruby 3 in the to_s method for the root Object. But indeed it's worth an issue on chef side, I'll make some tests and surface it on Chef's slack and on github when I'm sure of what's going on.

Comment: Thinking about it, that might be the reason. We're node attributes passed to the class back in Chef 12?

Comment: Yep the node object has always been passed. I didn't had time to pinpoint the root cause nor to open the issue on chef GitHub however. But as I've a mcve that should be easier to showcase now